# Tool for measuring Windows Service processes and used resources

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, load-testing, stress-testing

Hi
I wrote a stress test vor my WCF service, but the service is in the remote machine, Can I measure that windows service used process and other resources? Is there any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentialy you want a tool that monitors remote [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) events.

If you want integration with your stress test then Load Testing in Visual Studio 2008 provides monitoring of remote servers while executing the test ([this sample chapter](http://www.packtpub.com/files/software-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system-2008-sample-chapter-5-load-testing.pdf) on load testing provides details).

If you don't want to use Visual Studio then use the built-in [perfmon.msc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961845.aspx) to monitor a large variety of counters (such as cpu load, disk usage). This is probably your best option. For example if you look at the "ServiceModelService 3.0.0.0" object there are several WCF specific counters such as number of calls, calls faulted etc.

However prefmon does NOT (afaik) show you specific cpu usage per process. For this you will need a 3rd-party tool that will more specifically monitor cpu usage per process. Examples are:

- [Remote Process Explorer](http://lizardsystems.com/remote-process-explorer/index.php)
- [Remote Task Manager](http://www.devicelock.com/rtm/)
- [Remote Process Viewer](http://www.file.net/remote-process-viewer/)

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually done it, but I've read about attaching a profiler to a .NET service.  Here's an article that might give you some ideas:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255414.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to do without VS installing? It's for tester I don't think he will like the idea to install VS studio for that test :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using the performance monitor (perfmon.msc) to monitor various WMI events?

Comment: has it a feature to monitor only the measurements of a single service?

Comment: Perfmon.exe can monitor a single service, a single process, or an entire machine for things like service instances running, # of requests, etc.  This is definitely the way to go.